# Finding the sum $\frac{5}{12}+\frac{5}{36}+\frac{5}{72}+...+\frac{5}{5580}.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help to find a rule for the sum $$\frac{5}{12}+\frac{5}{36}+\frac{5}{72}+...+\frac{5}{5580}.$$

Comment: can you show the 4th and 5th term also ???

Comment: The $n^{th}$ term in the series isn't clear, is your question asking about the sum or a rule for the $n^{th}$ term? At least begin by factoring out $5/12$

Comment: my question is finding the sum of this series.

Comment: Can you show us the formula for the $n^{th}$ term? It's hard to find the sum without that

Comment: Factoring out the $5/12$ you get $$\frac{5}{12}\left(\frac11+\frac13+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{465}\right)$$ but it is not at all clear how you imagine the sequence $1, 3, 6,\ldots$ continues up to $465$.

Comment: the general formula is not included in the question. maybe there is a typing mistake in the question.

Comment: @andii: It is your question -- if there's a typing mistake in it, edit it to fix it!

Comment: maybe there is a mistake in the book. i wrote the full question

Comment: If I am not wrong, $a_n=\frac{5}{12}$ for $n=1$ and $a_n=\frac{5}{36n}$ for $n>1$. Is it correct @andii ???

Comment: @andii, from which section did this question arise in your book?

Comment: the section sequences and series

Comment: Any specific sequences? Perhaps constant second difference? I am afraid if you are not more specific your question might be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably though I can obviously not guarantee it, it is just $\frac{5}{6}$ times $\sum\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{30}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{30}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} = 30/31.$$
Therefore, one probable answer is 25/31.

Comment: Possibly you are jumping to conclusions...

Comment: Sure I cannot be 100% sure abut the pattern given the few terms but 6 times triangular numbers sure fits the few terms.

Comment: It does.It is 6*30*31.

Comment: This solution is absolutely correct. And $n=30$ fits the last term

Comment: Great thinking Tushant !!!

Comment: @VineetMangal, how can you be so sure?

Comment: Tell me the mistake in this solution @Dman. And if not, then this solution is correct !

Comment: Well, for starters, the next term could be $\frac{5}{73}$. All I am saying is that while this is a possible solution, we cannot know for certain if it is **the** solution. This, I believe is something that should be included in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, made a stupid calculation error, it fits like a glove.

Comment: @andii. Do you have the numerical answer to the problem so that my guess can be checked (though still not proved)?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer:

Notice that:

$$\frac{5}{12}+\frac{5}{36}+\frac{5}{72}+...+\frac{5}{5580}.=\frac{5}{12}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+...+\frac{1}{465}\right)$$

Now consider this and notice that the denominators of these fractions:$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+...+\frac{1}{465}$$

are triangular numbers.

Now the sequence for triangular numbers are $u_n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$

So now we can have it in the summation form:

$$\frac{5}{12}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+...+\frac{1}{465}\right)=\frac{5}{12} \sum_{n=1}^{30} \frac{1}{u_n}=\frac{5}{12} \sum_{n=1}^{30} \frac{2}{n^2+n}=\frac{5}{12}\frac{60}{31}=\frac{25}{31}$$